# Why is the Haar wavelet providing better frequency discrimination than alternatives?

Tags: time-series, frequency, wavelet

I'm using [PyWavelets](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt) (aka "pywt") to understand the discrete wavelet transform, and I'm trying to construct a crude power spectrum of a sinusoidal time series with frequency components of 1/8 and 1/32. The length of the series is $2^{10} = 1024$; the first 200 points are plotted below: 
[image]
The problem is, I can't figure out why the for-educational-use-only Haar wavelet is doing a better job picking out the frequencies than the other ones from the PyWavelets package (see output below code). *Can anyone explain what's going on?*

```
import numpy as np
import pywt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1024)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / 8) +  np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / 32)
plt.plot(x[0:200], y[0:200])
plt.show

def get_power_spectrum(y, wavelet):
  print("Using", wavelet, "wavelet")
  coefs = pywt.wavedec(y, wavelet, mode = 'sym', level = 10)

  for i in range(10):
    detail_i = coefs[i + 1]
    octave = 10 - i
    period = 2 ** octave
    frequency = 1 / period
    detail_norm = np.sqrt(detail_i.dot(detail_i)) / np.sqrt(len(detail_i))
    print("frequency is 1 / ", str(period), "=", round(frequency, 2),
          "has detail coef norm", str(round(detail_norm, 2)))

get_power_spectrum(y, 'haar')
get_power_spectrum(y, 'db2')
```

In the output below, you can see that the frequencies 1/8 and 1/32 pop for the Haar wavelet, but not so much for the db2 wavelet. Now the [db2 wavelet](http://wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/db2/) has a pretty gnarly shape, and I thought it might be too different from the shape of the original waveform, but the "sym" series didn't seem to fare any better.

```
Using haar wavelet
frequency is 1 /  1024 = 0.0 has detail coef norm 0.0
frequency is 1 /  512 = 0.0 has detail coef norm 0.0
frequency is 1 /  256 = 0.0 has detail coef norm 0.0
frequency is 1 /  128 = 0.01 has detail coef norm 0.0
frequency is 1 /  64 = 0.02 has detail coef norm 0.0
frequency is 1 /  32 = 0.03 has detail coef norm 3.59
frequency is 1 /  16 = 0.06 has detail coef norm 0.25
frequency is 1 /  8 = 0.13 has detail coef norm 1.86
frequency is 1 /  4 = 0.25 has detail coef norm 0.57
frequency is 1 /  2 = 0.5 has detail coef norm 0.4

Using db2 wavelet
frequency is 1 /  1024 = 0.0 has detail coef norm 1.68
frequency is 1 /  512 = 0.0 has detail coef norm 2.13
frequency is 1 /  256 = 0.0 has detail coef norm 1.58
frequency is 1 /  128 = 0.01 has detail coef norm 1.14
frequency is 1 /  64 = 0.02 has detail coef norm 0.79
frequency is 1 /  32 = 0.03 has detail coef norm 1.95
frequency is 1 /  16 = 0.06 has detail coef norm 2.34
frequency is 1 /  8 = 0.13 has detail coef norm 0.73
frequency is 1 /  4 = 0.25 has detail coef norm 1.31
frequency is 1 /  2 = 0.5 has detail coef norm 0.24
```